# Playing Animation with WxPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, wxpython, gif

I try to play a gif in my frame. I use this code in order to do it. Why doesn't it work?
(I use the last version of wxPython - 4.0.7.post2)

```
import wx
from wx.adv import AnimationCtrl

class Animate(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title)
        self.animation = AnimationCtrl(self)
        self.animation.LoadFile('scan.gif')
        self.animation.Play()
        self.Show()

app = wx.App()
frame = Animate(None, -1, 'Animation')
app.MainLoop()
```

[image: Frame]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to the constructor [`wx.adv.Animation`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.adv.Animation.html) is the filename. So it has to be:

```py
anim = wx.adv.Animation()
anim.LoadFile(r'C:\Users\yuval\PycharmProjects\MultiTyping\pictures\back_gif.gif')
```

or

```py
anim = wx.adv.Animation(r'C:\Users\yuval\PycharmProjects\MultiTyping\pictures\back_gif.gif')
```

Furthermore, I recommend to add a [`wx.BoxSizer`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.BoxSizer.html) to the frame:

```py
sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
sizer.Add(anim_ctrl)
frame.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
```

See the example:

```py
import wx
from wx.adv import AnimationCtrl, Animation

app=wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, title='2', pos=(0, 0), size=(200, 200))
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
anim = Animation(r'C:\Users\yuval\PycharmProjects\MultiTyping\pictures\back_gif.gif')
anim_ctrl = AnimationCtrl(frame, -1, anim)

sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
sizer.Add(anim_ctrl)
frame.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)

frame.Show()
anim_ctrl.Play()

app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I tried to run your code cut it still doesn't do anything @Rabbid76

Comment: Which type of gif do you use for it

Comment: @YuvalSharon [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/master/documentation/image/perspective_view_frustum.gif)

Comment: This line -  anim_ctrl = AnimationCtrl(frame, -1, anim), , throws me out with an exit code

Comment: @YuvalSharon As I said, it works fine fore me. Do you use the latest *wxPython* version?

Comment: I use wxpython.4.0.7.post2 I think that is it the last version of wxpython

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong with the answer given by @Rabbid76, I suggest that you run the code from the command line, rather than from within some ide.
Here is another take on your problem, it's as concise as I can make it and assumes a `local` file called `scan.gif`.

```
import wx
from wx.adv import AnimationCtrl

class Animate(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title)
        self.animation = AnimationCtrl(self)
        self.animation.LoadFile('scan.gif')
        self.animation.Play()
        self.Show()

app = wx.App()
frame = Animate(None, -1, 'Animation')
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I tried to run it from the Cmd and it still doesn't work

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Be precise and supply any errors you are getting.

Comment: Try another file. Even using a normal image (.png or .tiff or .jpg) my box shows the image. I assume it thinks it's a `gif` with a single frame.

Comment: The problem was the file, Thank you

Comment: Do you know how to put the gif as a background of the frame (I want to add above it buttons and more)?